# Does Shiva wear a garland having 11 skulls?

Tags: shiva, parvati, sati

Does [Shiva](https://youtu.be/h9Rmssvatmo?t=2528) wear a [garland](https://www.voot.com/shows/shrimad-bhagwat-mahapuran/1/801327/was-lord-rama-s-action-justified/805193) that has 11 skulls in it?
Are these Skulls of Sati? And why are there 11 skulls, specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Bhagawan Shiva wears the garland of infinite uncountable Skull.

Sri Skanda Purana 7.1.9.5-10:

> The Devī said.:
>
> 5. If you are the great Lord, the creator without beginning and end, the cause of creation and annihilation, how is it that a garland of skulls has been worn (by you)?
>
> 6-7. Thereupon, Śankara, the Lord of Devas, laughed and spoke these words.:
>
> “This garland of mine that shines with many crores of skulls has been made out of skulls of thousands of Nārāyaṇas and ten thousand Brahmās. **Therefore, it is devoid of beginning and end.**
>
> 8. A new Viṣṇu is born in every Kalpa. So also a new Brahmā. In every Kalpa, Viṣṇu and Prajāpati are created by me.
> 9. In this form, O goddess, I am stationed at the root of Kālāgni Liṅga in Prabhāsa. I am adorned with the garland of skulls.
> 10. I am quiescent without beginning, middle and end. I hold a rosary. I am seated in the lotus-posture. I am the bestower of boons. I resemble (in complexion) snow, a jasmine flower and the moon.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..